# how to have a hyperlink in custom web part property

Tags: web-part, properties, custom-web-part-property

i am working on a custom web part property and my question is how can i have hyper-link(seen in the below image) or bold or italic text in the custom property for the web part?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Tobias Zimmergren's post on the ToolPart:  http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/11/29/how-to-custom-web-part-properties-toolpart.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mike, i know how to add the custom prop to toolpart but my question was more like how can i have a hyperlink in the toolpart.

Comment: What I understood your question to be was how to get more control over how the properties can be displayed.  The ToolPart or something like it was essentially my answer.  A link is a string, so technically you can use a hyper-link today, it just woldn't have the "test link" option.

Comment: Mike's right. You'll need to manually build the 'Test Link' option, which will trigger a piece of Javascript to called window.open(), passing in the current value of the textbox which is used to store the property.